# How do I get jsFiddle to default to non-minized jQuery library?

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

Sometime recently, the default in jsFiddle (a tool I use all the time for answering questions here on StackOverflow) switched to use the minimized version of jQuery when you select the jQuery library option for it.  That means I can't make any sense of stepping into the jQuery library in the Chrome debugger and that's one of the main ways I learn how jQuery functions work that aren't well documented.

So, I'm wondering if anyone knows if there's anyway to change it to default to the non-minimized jQuery so it's easier to debug code that involves stepping through jQuery?

I know that I could manually link in the non-minimized version of jQuery by doing a `<script src=xxx>` to the Google CDN, but I'd much rather use jsFiddle's built-in functionality to select the appropriate library version, but just have it use the non-minimized version.  And, it used to use the non-minimized version.  It's a test tool after all so it makes sense to me to at least have an option to use the non-minified version.

Comment: Why the downvote on the question?  Is this not a legitimate thing to ask about?

Comment: This is a perfectly fair question. +1

Comment: I didn't DV, but it really doesn't seem like a programming question to me. Seems like a support/feature request question for jsFiddle.

Comment: It's a programming related tools question.  I have probably created 500 jsFiddles in the last year in solving and answering questions here on SO.  If anyone cares to direct me to a better place to ask, I'm happy to go somewhere better.  I couldn't find anywhere better which is why I posted here.

Comment: Fair enough, but honestly, everyone here is looking at the same jsFiddle that you are, so I just don't know what sort of answer you're expecting. Only jsFiddle can answer why they changed their site, and if there's no option given to revert it, then well... there's no option other than the workarounds you're already familiar with. Given that, it seems more like a discussion piece than an answerable question *(in its current form anyway)*.

Comment: I was hoping maybe there were some options I wasn't aware of or some nonobvious way to configure it. -

Comment: This is a little nuts to say that this question is off topic.  Right in the off topic msg it says that questions should: "relate to programming or software development in some way".  Quoting directly from the FAQ, one area of appropriate questions is questions that: "cover software tools commonly used by programmers".  This question relates to both of those.  jsFiddle is a tool heavily used by programmers and heavily used by SO questions/answerers.  I simply had a question about the use of jsFiddle which there seems to be no other appropriate place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

I had to dig down deep but I found the email address of a jsFiddle developer.

piotr (at sign) zalewa.info

I would think he would be the only one who could truly answer this question.

You have actually answered your own question though.

I had asked this developer "zalun" about making jQuery the default JavaScript library and he said it would be eventually but for now to setup a default fiddle and fork from it as needed.

Fork from this as needed:

http://jsfiddle.net/prbGP/

It's No-Library (pure JS) framework with the added resource of Google's CDN jQuery non-minified latest version.

Comment: OK, that's one idea.  That will fool the heck out of people that I share it with thought because they won't see that it's got jQuery included.